# iReport - parameterize schema name?

Tags: jasper-reports, schema, ireport

I have the following query :

```sql
SELECT
     blah
FROM
     "PUBLIC"."MYACTIVITY" MYACTIVITY
```

The problem is, the schema name is different for different environments. I tried making `"PUBLIC"` a parameter like this:

```sql
SELECT
     blah
FROM
     "$P{schemaName}"."MYACTIVITY" MYACTIVITY
```

while setting `schemeName` before I compile the report in the params, but no matter what I do, or what the default value is set as, I get the following error:

`Error:SQL problems:invalid schema name: ? in statement [SELECT blah FROM "?"."MYACTIVITY" MYACTIVITY`

How do I properly parameterize the schema name for this report?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `$P!{schemaName}`. Note the exclamation mark. Use double quotes in the value:

```
SELECT
     blah
FROM
     $P!{schemaName}."MYACTIVITY" MYACTIVITY
```

And:

Let `schemaName` = `"PUBLIC"` (include the quotes).

The `$P{}` substitution provides an interpreted value, whereas `$P!{}` uses the literal value. You can use `$P!{}` to change the query itself.

Comment: I actually found this in iReport shortly after posting this, but the wording didn't make sense, and I couldn't find any documentation when I googled the terminology iReport was using. I feel like this needs more documentation or visibility or something :P.

Comment: Yes. `$X{}` and `$P!{}` need more light shone upon them. Searching the Web for non-alphanumeric characters is problematic.

Comment: `$X{}` allows for `IN` clauses.